# Lazy loading images of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uiimage, lazy-loading

I have a `UITableView` with different sections and every cell has a image on it.
Because the images are downloaded separate for each cell, I'm looking for a lazy loading solution.

On the iOS Developer Library their is a good solution for my problem but it is in Objective-c.
([Link to LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html))

I've tried the example on the Xamarin site ([Link](http://docs2.xamarin.com/ios/Samples/Details/LazyTableImages)) but it is not fast and buggy with sections.

I found this ([UrlImageStore](https://github.com/sichy/UrlImageStore)) solution but I can't get it working with the `UITableView`.

Anybody a tip/solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to not reinvent the wheel, Xamarin has created a sample on this. It's updated too.

Just search for **LazyTableImages** project in [monotouch samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples).

I provided the main page of samples since it could be helpful to you.

Comment: I have tried the Xamarin sample but it's buggy at the moment with my solution. I'm using multiple sections and the images can have three different values (UIActivityIndicatorView while loading the image, the image downloaded from the server or the 'No image found' image). Maybe I should try the sample from Xamarin with custom cells...

Comment: The problem is the UIActivityIndicatorView that I add to the cell view. If I remove that, everything went fine...

Answer (score 3):

The UrlImageStore is a very nice solution. You should not try to make this work with an UITableView, but with custom cells or elements.

I used [TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation) as a reference and based my own solution on his code.

Comment: The TweetStation is build with MonoTouch.Dialog if I look quick at it and thats now not an option for me.

Comment: OK, my bad, I did not expect you to work without MonoTouch.Dialog. It still might be a good starting point, as it's implementation is similar to the UrlImageStore you found.